# c# - How to iterate through classes fields and set properties

Tags: c#, class, properties, set, field

I am not sure if this is possible but I want to iterate through a class and set a field member property without referring to the field object explicitly:

```
public class Employee
{
  public Person _person = new Person();

  public void DynamicallySetPersonProperty()
  {
    MemberInfo[] members = this.GetType().GetMembers();

    foreach (MemberInfo member in members.Where(a => a.Name == "_person"))
    //get the _person field
    {

      Type type = member.GetType();
      PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("Name"); //good, this works, now to set a value for it

      //this line does not work - the error is "property set method not found"
      prop.SetValue(member, "new name", null);
    }
  }
}


public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the answer that I marked as the answer you need to add:

```
  public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string source)
  {
    return (source == null || source.Length > 0) ? true : false;
  }
```

Comment: This fails because you tried to set the property name on the memberinfo object. Member Info has a name, but it's not the [_person]'s name.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Person person = new Person();

    public void DynamicallySetPersonProperty()
    {
        var p = GetType().GetField("person").GetValue(this);
        p.GetType().GetProperty("Name").SetValue(p, "new name", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to add var p = person.GetType()... as I ended up calling it from a different class

Comment: This doesn't work. It should've been `GetProperty` instead of `GetField`.

Answer (score 37):

Here's a complete working example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void PropertySet(object p, string propName, object value)
    {
        Type t = p.GetType();
        PropertyInfo info = t.GetProperty(propName);
        if (info == null)
            return;
        if (!info.CanWrite)
            return;
        info.SetValue(p, value, null);
    }

    static void PropertySetLooping(object p, string propName, object value)
    {
        Type t = p.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in t.GetProperties())
        {
            if (info.Name == propName && info.CanWrite)
            {
                info.SetValue(p, value, null);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p = new Person();

        PropertySet(p, "Name", "Michael Ellis");
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        PropertySetLooping(p, "Name", "Nigel Mellish");
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }
}
```

EDIT: added a looping variant so you could see how to loop through property info objects.

Answer (score 10):

With the following Extension methods that I have created, you can set or get any property value even if they are nested

GetPropertyValue(customObject, "Property.Nested.Child.Name");

or set

SetPropertyValue(customObject, "Property.Nested.Child.Name", "my custom name");

```
        private class TargetProperty
    {
        public object Target { get; set; }
        public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }

        public bool IsValid { get { return Target != null && Property != null; } }
    }

    private static TargetProperty GetTargetProperty(object source, string propertyName)
    {
        if (!propertyName.Contains("."))
            return new TargetProperty { Target = source, Property = source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) };

        string[] propertyPath = propertyName.Split('.');

        var targetProperty = new TargetProperty();

        targetProperty.Target = source;
        targetProperty.Property = source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyPath[0]);

        for (int propertyIndex = 1; propertyIndex < propertyPath.Length; propertyIndex++)
        {
            propertyName = propertyPath[propertyIndex];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                targetProperty.Target = targetProperty.Property.GetValue(targetProperty.Target, null);
                targetProperty.Property = targetProperty.Target.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            }
        }

        return targetProperty;
    }


    public static bool HasProperty(this object source, string propertyName)
    {
        return GetTargetProperty(source, propertyName).Property != null;
    }

    public static object GetPropertyValue(this object source, string propertyName)
    {
        var targetProperty = GetTargetProperty(source, propertyName);
        if (targetProperty.IsValid)
        {
            return targetProperty.Property.GetValue(targetProperty.Target, null);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void SetPropertyValue(this object source, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        var targetProperty = GetTargetProperty(source, propertyName);
        if(targetProperty.IsValid)
        {
            targetProperty.Property.SetValue(targetProperty.Target, value, null);
        }
    }
```

And here are a couple of tests for it

```
    [TestFixture]
public class ObjectExtensionsTest
{

    private class MockClass
    {
        public MockClass()
        {
            Nested = new NestedMockClass();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string GetOnly { get { return "MockClass"; } }
        public string SetOnly { set { } }

        public NestedMockClass Nested { get; set; }
    }

    private class NestedMockClass
    {
        public string NestedId { get; set; }
        public string NestedName { get; set; }

        public string NestedGetOnly { get { return "NestedMockClass"; } }
        public string NestedSetOnly { set { } }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestShouldFindProperty()
    {
        MockClass mockObject = new MockClass();

        Assert.IsTrue(mockObject.HasProperty("Id"));
        Assert.IsTrue(mockObject.HasProperty("Name"));
        Assert.IsTrue(mockObject.HasProperty("GetOnly"));
        Assert.IsTrue(mockObject.HasProperty("SetOnly"));
        Assert.IsTrue(mockObject.HasProperty("Nested"));
        Assert.IsTrue(mockObject.HasProperty("Nested.NestedId"));
        Assert.IsTrue(mockObject.HasProperty("Nested.NestedName"));
        Assert.IsTrue(mockObject.HasProperty("Nested.NestedGetOnly"));
        Assert.IsTrue(mockObject.HasProperty("Nested.NestedSetOnly"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestShouldGetPropertyValue()
    {
        MockClass mockObject = new MockClass();

        mockObject.Id = "1";
        mockObject.Name = "Name";
        mockObject.Nested.NestedId = "NestedId";
        mockObject.Nested.NestedName = "NestedName";

        Assert.AreEqual(mockObject.Id, mockObject.GetPropertyValue("Id"));
        Assert.AreEqual(mockObject.Name, mockObject.GetPropertyValue("Name"));
        Assert.AreEqual(mockObject.GetOnly, mockObject.GetPropertyValue("GetOnly"));
        Assert.AreEqual(mockObject.Nested.NestedId, mockObject.GetPropertyValue("Nested.NestedId"));
        Assert.AreEqual(mockObject.Nested.NestedName, mockObject.GetPropertyValue("Nested.NestedName"));

    }

    [Test]
    public void TestShouldSetPropertyValue()
    {
        MockClass mockObject = new MockClass();

        mockObject.SetPropertyValue("Id", "1");
        mockObject.SetPropertyValue("Name", "Name");
        mockObject.SetPropertyValue("Nested.NestedId", "NestedId");
        mockObject.SetPropertyValue("Nested.NestedName", "NestedName");

        Assert.AreEqual(mockObject.Id, "1");
        Assert.AreEqual(mockObject.Name, "Name");
        Assert.AreEqual(mockObject.Nested.NestedId, "NestedId");
        Assert.AreEqual(mockObject.Nested.NestedName, "NestedName");

    }
}
```

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Very nice... especially with nesting.  Plinth's example is simpler, but has no nesting.  Also, for anyone else landing here who (like me) had to dig around to understand what the heck "extensions" were, this is a good and concise explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to set the Name property of your Employee class's _person field. It doesn't have one. Try this:

```
prop.SetValue(((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(this), "new name", null)
```

Not sure if you need to cast the first argument like this:

```
prop.SetValue((Person)((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(this), "new name", null)
```

This then applies it to the value of the _person field instead.

Answer (score 5):

You a trying to perform `SetValue()` on the property `Name` of the variable `member` that is a MemberInfo object and this proeprty is read only.

Note you do not need to iterate over all memebers and you do not need to get the field `_person` with reflection as it is defined in the same class as the method `DynamicallySetPersonProperty()`.

So the code shoul read like this.

```
PropertyInfo property = this._person.GetType().GetProperty("Name");

property.SetValue(this._person, "new name", null);
```

The first line will fail if `_person` is null. So you can use reflectiopn to get the type of the field.

```
FieldInfo field = this.GetType().GetField("_person", BindingFlags.Public);

PropertyInfo property = field.FieldType.GetProperty("Name");
```

But now accessing this property will still fail if `_person`is null.

```
property.Setvalue(field.GetValue(this), "new name", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static void ApplyPropertyChanges(this object objDest, object objToCopyFrom)
    {
        if (objDest == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (objToCopyFrom == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("objToCopyFrom");
        if (objDest.GetType() != objToCopyFrom.GetType())
            throw new Exception("Invalid type. Required: \"" + objDest.GetType().ToString() + "\"");

        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piOrig in objDest.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            object editedVal = objToCopyFrom.GetType().GetProperty(piOrig.Name).GetValue(objToCopyFrom, null);

            piOrig.SetValue(objDest,
            editedVal,
            null);
        }
    }
```

usage example:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(Team editedTeamData)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        Team origTeam = (from t in _db.Teams
                         where t.TeamID == editedTeamData.TeamID
                         select t).FirstOrDefault();

        origTeam.ApplyPropertyChanges(editedTeamData);
        _db.SubmitChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```