# how to run through each class item and set value to it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, class, foreach

I have a class that contains some items of different datatypes.  I want to set value to each item and send it from controller to view, and view data in text boxes.

Is it possible to loop through these the objects in the class, check the data type of it, and then assign a value to each one?

Here's a pseudo code example of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
foreach item in class ItemProduction
{
    if data type  == string 
        value of item = " " ; 

    if data type  == int
        value of item = 0 ; 

    if data type  == DAte
       value of item = date of today ;          
 }
```

Here my class definition and the objects inside it.

```
public class ItemProduction : Common, IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Main{ get; set; }
    public DateTime itemDate { get; set; }
    public string ItemType{ get; set; }
    public string productionId{ get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Do you just want to initialize the List of `ItemProduction`?

Comment: @Bhushan Firake i want to set value to each item, but first i want to check the data type of each one

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 List<ItemProduction> items = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new ItemProduction
 {
      Main = string.Empty,
      ItemDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
      ItemType = string.Empty,
      ProductionId = string.Empty,
      Quantity = 0,
      Status = string.Empty
 }).ToList();
```

This will create 5 instances of `ItemProduction` and initialize all of them with the values given as per your need.

The best bet is to have a constructor in your ItemProduction model as below:

```
public class ItemProduction
{
   public string Main { get; set; }
   public DateTime TtemDate { get; set; }
   public string ItemType { get; set; }
   public string ProductionId { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }

   public ItemProduction()
   {
       this.Main = string.Empty;
       this.ItemDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
       this.ItemType = string.Empty;
       this.ProductionId = string.Empty;
       this.Quantity = 0;
       this.Status = string.Empty;
   }
}
```

So, the above code will simply become

```
List<ItemProduction> items= Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new ItemProduction()).ToList();
```

**Note:**

It is a convention to have class properties as PascalCase, so I have amended your class with nest naming convention.You can go through this [Property Naming Guidelines.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**Update:**

If you have many properties, you can do this using reflection as below:

```
public static T Init<T>(T TObject)
{
  var properties = TObject.GetType().GetProperties();
  foreach (var property in properties)
  {
     if (property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
     {
         property.SetValue(TObject, string.Empty);
     }
     else if (property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(int)))
     {
         property.SetValue(TObject, 0);
     }
     else if (property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
     {
         property.SetValue(TObject, DateTime.UtcNow);
     }
  }
  return TObject;
}
```

Comment: but if i want to set value to many more items , not only  5 ?

Comment: @user2269364 just pass the number of items you want to set value for..

Comment: yeah yeah  but i mean when i set values, shall i set value to each one , one by one ?

Comment: ok, its too much job. i was thinking about en foreach loop that check the data type of each item and set value to it. somthing like  if(item.data type is string)
              {
                  item.value = "" ;
              }

Comment: @user2269364 So, as your problem is resolved, can you consider accepting my answer?

Comment: is it no way to do how im thinking ??                                                                                          i was thinking about en foreach loop that check the data type of each item and set value to it. somthing like if(item.data type is string) { item.value = "" ; }

Comment: @user2269364 Yes, this can surely be done. but what I have answered is generally the approach used all over.It also leverages the concept of class. using a constructor simlpifies the work.

Comment: my class containes 60 variables that needs values, i want the right syntax to set value to each one, not manuely one by one! i want functione to do that

Comment: @user2269364 See my updated answer..you can call this method on the list of items. Also it is generic so can be used on any kind of object.

Comment: Error 17 No overload for method 'SetValue' takes 2 arguments  i changed it to properity.SetValue(TObject, string.Empty,null);  Then i got Property set method not found on this line

Comment: @user2269364 you must have called it in wrong way...it works fine at my end.

Comment: ItemProduct i = new ItemProduct(); // new object of class    
 // and then function coll    
Init(i) // call the function and give the object as parameter. whats wrong ?

Comment: @user2269364 You need to do it as `ItemProduct i = new ItemProduct(); Init<ItemProduct>(i);`, you were doing it wrong. Please accept my answer, as this solves your problem.

Comment: i will accept it.
but i still have problem, the foreach loop starts and make 51 lopps and my items are 52. got Property set method not found  on this line :  if (properity.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
                    { properity.SetValue(TObject, string.Embty, null); }

Comment: @user2269364 have u passed 52 in that method?

Comment: there are 53 variables in my class,
i havnt passed any number in the method, is it possible ?

Comment: @user2269364 I am refering it here:` Enumerable.Range(1, 5)`. Instead of 5 , pass 53

Comment: this range makes so many lists !! in my case it makes 5 or 52 listes each one contains en class ItemProduct !!

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to set value based on datatype using if statement.
If you want to simply pass an object of this ItemProduction class as a model to your view, simply have a constructor for your ItemProduction class and initialize your model value with default values and send it to your view

```
 public class ItemProduction 
{
    public string Main { get; set; }
    public DateTime itemDate { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public string productionId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public ItemProduction()
    {
        Main = "main value";
        itemDate =DateTime.Now;
        ItemType ="type";
        productionId ="productionId";
        Quantity =5;
        Status = "status";
    }
}
```

if you want to dynamically set values using reflection, refer this question:
[c# - How to iterate through classes fields and set properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721441/c-sharp-how-to-iterate-through-classes-fields-and-set-properties?rq=1)

Comment: Is it different than what I said in my answer?